# root view controller at the end of application launch, defaulting to cocos2d viewcontroller instead of another storyboard view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, interface-builder

[This question is based on this tutorial](http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Cocos2D+v2.1+and+Storyboards+Done+Right)

The linked tutorial is on how to use cocos2d along with Storyboards. My problem is that, with a new and clean project and the tutorial followed perfectly, the app launches with the default cocos2d-helloworld screen instead of an interfacebuilder screen I made, and the console is logging

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

How do I set the intended window to be launched at the beginning instead? Any tips on what the root view controller means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

search in that tutorial "Adding a Storyboard to your Project" there you set the main story board, this story board is the rootViewController you miss

and more lines above you can see the topic "Connecting the Storyboard View Controllers"

maybe you can follow again the tutorial with making all steps.